# The CD command with "-" argument will change to previous directory. Is there a way to know which directory it is?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The command

> cd -

will change the pwd to the last directory.

Is there a way to know which directory it is, so that I'll know where I am CD'ing to?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it is $OLDPWD.

```
~$ cd src/
~/src$ cd ..
~$ echo $OLDPWD
/home/$USER/src
```

Comment: Always a pleasure :)

Comment: "echo ~-" will output the same information

Answer (score 5):

The previous directory is saved in $OLDPWD

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ~- (anywhere you can use tilde expansion) instead of $OLDPWD:

```
# Copy a file from the previous working directory.
cp ~-/file1 .
```

There is also ~+ for $PWD, which is useful for commands which require an absolute directory:

```
./configure --prefix ~+/root
```

Note that things like `--prefix=~+/root` won't work due to the rules of tilde expansion; use `--prefix="$PWD/root"` instead.